# Read date using date entry in tkinter and searching using date in sqlite table and printing it in a treeview

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

So, I have an **DateEntry** where the user inputs the desired date and there is a view **Button**. When the view button is clicked, it should diplay data in a **TreeView**, which is in **daily.py** file.

```
cal = DateEntry(eframe, width=12, background='darkblue',
                        foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
cal.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=15)
Button(eframe, text="View",command=view(cal)).grid(row=4, column=6)
```

And I have defined a function in **db.py** which has following code:

```
def view(cal):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("transactiondb.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT  category,income_amount, note FROM transactions WHERE date="+cal.get())
    rec=cur.fetchall()
    print(rec)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

But for now I am just trying it to print in the terminal, but it just prints an **empty set[]**.

I know there is some error when I call **cal.get()**.

can anyone tell me the solution and correct my error.

Comment: Try `cur.execute("SELECT ... WHERE date = ?", [cal.get()])`.  Also `command=view(cal)` should be `command=lambda: view(cal)`.

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked @acw1668